# Accessing local objects of another method

Tags: java, android

I am basically testing using the location for my android app. All it currently does is show some TextViews with the latitude and longitude of the user's location. However, what I wish to have is for the LocationListener to stop receiving updates after it has received a location, not for it to continue listening for updates.

```
public void updateLocation(Location location, Geocoder geocoder){
    TextView lat=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.lat);
    TextView longt=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.longt);    
    double lata=location.getLatitude();
    double longa=location.getLongitude();
    lat.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
    longt.setText(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
}

public void FindLocation(Context context){
    final LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(){
          public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        updateLocation(location);}
          public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
          public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
          public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
      };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
} 
}
```

This should be done after updateLocation() has been called but it cannot reference locationManager nor locationListener. I also cannot call it inside FindLocation() after updateLocation() has been called as 'Cannot refer to a non-final variable locationListener inside an inner class defined in a different method'. However, adding final to locationListener only yields the error 'locationListener may not have been initialised'. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me what you are looking for is to use the locationListener itself in one of its methods. You can do this with 'this'.

```
public void FindLocation(Context context){
    final LocationManager locationManager (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(){
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
            updateLocation(location);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make locationManager a class variable and final so you can reference it from anywhere within the class.

```
private final LocationManager locationManager;
```

and then define it inside onCreate like below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



locationManager =(LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(){
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    updateLocation(location);}
      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

Comment: Aaaarrrrhhhhhgggg.  My eyes are falling out of their sockets.  My nose is melting and my dog is howling.  The "global" disease is still here on SO.  This is NOT a global variable, which by definition has scope and life time equal to the application.  This is a class field (or class variable).  -1 until you fix it.  Where did you learn that a class field is global?  Please tell me so I can  insert something spiky into whoever wrote it!

Comment: haha, thanks for cheering me up at 3:00AM in Silicon Valley. fixed! :)

Comment: Would this be the better approach or using locationManager.removeUpdates(this) as mentioned in the other comment?

Comment: @cortex  Either works.  It's a question of style.  Personally, I prefer ljgw's answer since it limits the scope of the location manager.  Good OOP design dictates that everything should have the smallest possible scope.

Comment: @Simon that is true, but when dealing with location, in a realistic scenario you will be dealing with the manager frequently and would probably want to avoid repetition. (correct me if I'm wrong please).

Comment: Take a look at interfaces and listeners.  you can easily write your own to send location updates to any other class and for other classes to control your location manager.  Access is only provided outside the owning class via the interface(s) so everything must subscribe to, and conform with the contract the interface sets.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a private field of the class, like this:

```
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
public void FindLocation(Context context){
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
...
}
```

Now you can access mLocationManager from anywhere in the class.